# Extracting table from email using gmail api in python

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

I want to extract table from email, mail is shows table when viewed in email client

here is email snapshot

[image]

I want to process table, but couldn't find way to get it in python code

Here is extract for raw data

`decoded_data = base64.b64decode(data)`

is showing
`b'a d g\r\nb e h\r\nc f j\r\na d\r\nb e h\r\nc f j\r\n\r\nBest Regards,\r\nVikrant Pawar\r\n'`

While soup gives it like

`soup = BeautifulSoup(decoded_data, "lxml")`

it shows

```
<html><body><p>a d g
b e h
c f j
a d
b e h
c f j

Best Regards,
Vikrant Pawar
</p></body></html>
```

Is there a way where I can get table data which could be imported in pandas

Answer (score 2):

You can split your data and form list of tables from it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

text = """
<html><body><p>a d g
b e h
c f j
a d
b e h
c f j

Best Regards,
Vikrant Pawar
</p></body></html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')
data = soup.p.text
list_of_tables = data.split('\n')
# -> ['a d g', 'b e h', 'c f j', 'a d', 'b e h', 'c f j', '', 'Best Regards,', 'Vikrant Pawar', '']
```

*Note that* if there are extra `\r`'s along with `\n`'s, you should split by `data.split('\n\r')`. Now you can get the part you need to form a pandas df. Let's say you only want parts before 'Best Regards'. To do it,  we first need to slice list then split each element to form pandas df:

```
list_of_tables = [each.split() for each in list_of_tables[:6]]
# -> [['a', 'd', 'g'], ['b', 'e', 'h'], ['c', 'f', 'j'], ['a', 'd'], ['b', 'e', 'h'], ['c', 'f', 'j']]
```

Now all we need to do is to form dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_tables)
```

Final result would look like this:

```
   0  1     2
0  a  d     g
1  b  e     h
2  c  f     j
3  a  d  None
4  b  e     h
5  c  f     j
```